# exchange or share or another word

Tags: word-choice, word-request

When a few people or groups of people give each other something they do not have at first to utilize, which word would be correct to use?

For example, my friends and I have a dictionary while we need more sheets of papers or books. We give them our dictionary and we get allowed to use their books we need. Since we do not take  the books or give the dictionary permanently, I doubt that the word exchange is correct. On the other hand, the word share connotes a situation that both groups use the same thing at the same time. Is there a word for the scenario?

Comment: "share connotes a situation that both groups use the same thing" is OK, but it doesn't have to mean at the same time. But both parties need to have access of the object or information at any time. Other than that, could you write some example sentences describing your situation?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are `borrowing` the books, using the dictionary as `security`. In a similar fashion, one may `borrow` money from a bank (the bank is the `lender`) to buy a house. The house is `security`, i.e. if the borrower cannot pay back the loan, the bank gets the house (or at least part of its value).

Answer (score 1):

While **borrow** and **share** fit quite OK, you may be looking for ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pooling)):

> **pooling** (n.) = **the act of sharing** or combining **two or more things**:
>
> - the pooling of resources

Another example of the use would be **car pooling** (although things work slightly different than you described).